# What is "Nepomuk Backup" and why is it installed?

Tags: package-management, uninstall

I've noticed a new item under *Applications -> System Tools:* `Nepomuk Backup`.
I haven't installed it, and it just showed up recently.

Why is it there and why was it installed (possibly with some other KDE program) without my consent?
Is it safe to remove it?

[image: Nepomuk Backup]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably a dependency for a program that you installed (probably KDE based), as far as I know you cannot remove it without affecting the application.

Have a look at the [page project](http://nepomuk.kde.org/) and the [wiki entry for the framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEPOMUK_%28framework%29).

You can check what packages depend on that one using `apt-rdepends` (install it if you don't have it):

Usage for checking is `apt-rdepends -d <nameofpackage>`, other options can be found on the [man()](http://www.debianadmin.com/manpages/aptrdependsmanpage.htm) page for `rdepends`.